# Rectangle class functions getX(), getY(), etc. return in double precision

Tags: java, rectangles

Well I know they do, according to my experience and the Oracle Java API documentation, but I wonder why.
Through the constructor I'm only allowed to pass `int` type arguments to the `Rectangle` class, the internal data representation of x, y, etc. are of the type `int` and also `setSize()` only excepts arguments of the type `int`.
But why do all methods like `getX()`, `getY()`, `getWidth()`, etc. return a double when there can not be any precision? Why not simple `int`s as expected?

EDIT:
I do understand that it is derived from the `Rectangle2D` class, but that is still no reason to just simply not provide any `int`-based `getX()` and `getY()` functions, as in difference with the `Point` and `Point2D` class those methods are not abstract. Also `setLocation()` is not abstract either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe because it extends [Rectangle2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html) which is used in [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html), and it says :

> This class is only the abstract superclass for all objects that store a 2D rectangle. **The actual storage representation of the coordinates is left to the subclass.**

So if any of its subclass represents the dimensions in `double` should be compatible with one another, perhaps. If you read the Javadoc for [Rectangle#getX()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#getX()):

> Returns the X coordinate of the bounding Rectangle in double precision.
>
> **Specified by:**
>
> [public abstract double getX()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.html#getX()) in class RectangularShape.

Comment: But getX(), getY(), getWidth() methods does not inherited from Rectangle2D. So, why their return type is double?

Comment: Ah of course, they are specified in the `RectangularShape` class. Thansk a lot, I was wondering about this for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I think they put them for perpose:
If some API needs the `int` version of the x or y coordinate then it can directly use recObject.x or recObject.y respectively.
If some API needs the `double` version of the x or y coordinate then it can use getX() and getY()

Comment: Isn't that considered bad practice, to use the class fields directly and not through a getter/setter in Java ?

Comment: @Jori: Because , it is quite an old API. The programmer who wrote it might not look into this matter. And later for the backward compatibility sun java can't change the variable access modifier to private .